# Angular component styling convention

Tags: css, angular, conventions

Suppose I have to create the below layout :-
[image]

I can write all the `<card>` specific styles in the `card.component.css`. But as you can see in the image, each `<card>` has a specific width. How and where do I set this style?

Should I do something like this in the `parent.component.css` ?

```
card{
    width: 200px;
}
```

Are there any alternatives? Does there exists a method to style the component in the `card.component.css` itself? What is the recommended method to do something like this? Should I even directly style the `<card>` tag?

I know that this is a opinion based question, but clear and well defined conventions and mental models can help beginners like me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Should I do something like this?

Yes why not? Maybe use % values as width in order to be flexible, also you might want to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in your parent.component.css if you want to ensure adaptability to screen width.

2. Are there alternatives?

Yes there are alternatives you could use Imports like the other answer explained. Or Define a different style URL in the StyleURL of the card component see here [Angular CSS Component Styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles). And there are probably more alternatives.

3. What is the recommended method to do something like this? Should I even directly style the  tag?

The idea behind the components is of course that a style class should style all elements with the same style. From your picture I would assume the style of the card tag is the same therefore one should use the parent.component.css to style these elements. Regarding the second part you might want to read about [ngClass](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngclass-ngstyle/) I would use div container and not style elements directly, since I encountered misbehaving of elements with direct styling.

Comment: Suppose I want the cards to have `display : inline-block`. If I use a `div` container wrapper inside the `card` component and apply the styles to it, the parent `<card>` tag will still have the default `display : block`. This could break my layout. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could work with a different display property like `display: inline-flex` see the documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). I prepared a little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/inline-flex?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) to a possible solution.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. You mentioned in your answer that "I would use div container and not style elements directly, since I encountered misbehaving of elements with direct styling." Can you give example of such misbehavior?

Comment: Just think about it as an additional layer to decouple the style of the container and the style of the element, as those might defer from one another. But I dont have a specific example for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a specfic width to the card component from the parent and inside the card component use ng style binding.
So, in your card component. the html will look something like this:

```
<div [style.width.px]="width">some texts </div>
```

and in the card component ts you'll have a width property with the @Input decorator:

```
@Input() width: number;
```

In the Parent component, you may pass specific width based on index. for example, in this script i pass the width for each component multiplied by the current card index.

```
<card *ngFor="let c of cards; let i = index" width="index * 200"></card>
```

Comment: What if I have something like this - `<card style="width: 200px"></card>`? Is this valid?

Comment: But you said that you want each card to have a differnt width.

Comment: are you rendering it via ngFor in the parent component?

Comment: I did not mean that. I want to confirm if styling a component like `<card style="width: 200px"></card>` is valid or not.

Comment: it's valid depend on what you want to achieve. I prefer doing a more generic styling followed by class but in your case, if you want to exclude a specific card, you may use the style attribute which will override the rest of the cards ruling because of the specification rules of css. @PraneetDixit

Comment: @PraneetDixit Does it answer your question?